# Change color and font of a string using NSAttributed String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, addattribute

I have a string in which last word would always be of a different color compared to the other words in entire string eg: if the string color is black then last word in the statement would be of red color. I am using NSAttributed string for it as below:

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIFont fontWithName:Arial size:16.0] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *AattrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is a" attributes: attrDict];
```

I would be making similar NSAttributedString for the last word and will the amend it with first string.

***Question:*** I want to add color to the string along with the font. I am already handling the font using dictionary. But can I add the color handler/code in the same dictionary or using "addAttribute:" on NSAttributedString is the only other way to add color or any other attributes?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add the color to the same dictionary as the font:

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{
    NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:Arial size:16.0],
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
};
```